# iOS Auto-Renewable Subscriptions with sandbox test account

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have changed my client's current non renewable subscription in app purchase to an auto-renewable one, and when I test it on my iPhone with a test sandbox account it shows the "" message and goes through successfully. I receive all the content I would normally get, but I noticed the amount of days that gets returned from the "daysRemainingOnSubscriptionForProductWithIdentifier: productIdentifier" increases by ~1400 every time i try to purchase it again. Also, it doesn't seem to show if it auto renews or not (6 months -> 30 minutes)... The subscriptions remain paid even when I close the app out and delete it. Is this all part of the sandbox testing and how it functions? Because the in app purchase is/was working fine, I just created a new auto-renewable in app purchase product in itunes connect and replaced the productID of the non renewing subscription with the new auto-renewable one in the .plist file. Does anyone have any experience with this?